# Add ICS compatibility after developing for Lollipop

Tags: android

**Problem:** I made an app for the Android 5.1 Platform. I now need to make it compatible with ICS. What is the best way to accomplish that?

I know that I should have set the minSDK to ICS when I started the project, but now I essentially want to change the minSDK in the middle of the project.

I am using android studio as the IDE (latest release).

Answer (score 0):

Since you using minSdk=22 from the beginning Android Studio does not alarm you about incompatibilities issues.

First of all you should change midSdk of course. Than review all the sources for incompatibility warnings like 'using new android api'. Such analysis easily can be done with 'lint'. When you find one do not suppress it with @TargetApi, but write additional code to work around.

Something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    do_your_magic();
} else {
    add_additional_code_for_pre_lollipop();
}
```

Looks ugly but this is the world we live in)

Also you may find some 'deprecated methods' warnings, leave them alone, they does not matter for your question.

There can be some other cases. Maybe it will be necessary to include support-v7 and change your Activities. Maybe you using libraries that do not support ICS. Not knowing project details can't help much.